# htaccess redirect code: wildcard in middle of path

Tags: redirect, wildcard

I have searched for an answer here but have not been able to find one that meets my precise criteria.

I would like to redirect the following url:

```
http://site.com/term1/9/title
```

to

```
http://site.com/term1/title
```

There are two additional considerations:

1. The "term1" above could be any word; and
2. The number "9" above could be any number from 1 through 100.

I would be grateful for any assistance with this.

Many thanks in advance, david

Answer (score 0):

[Apache RewriteRule directives use perl compatible regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)/(\d+)/(.*) $1/$3
```

I tested it on an [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and I got the correct result. Of course, you may need to adjust the regular expression if you expect any other characters in the first part of the address. If you really need to catch the 1-100 range, you can use a more complex regular expression instead of just `\d+`, in the second parentheses: `[0-9]{1,2}|100`.